# Replace text in file using JREPL.BAT

Tags: batch-file, jrepl

My batch script is supposed to replace content within a file or list of files, but doesn't work and unfortunately exits cycle loop...

Here the code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "int=000"
set "int_new=111"
for %%i in ("c:\text.txt") do (
    jrepl "!int!" "!int_new!" /m /f "c:\text.txt" /o "c:\text_2.txt"
)
pause
```

It replaces the text but exit the script, could you explain where my mistake is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `JREPL` is a separate script from your script, when you run `JREPL` directly like that, the flow of your script transfers to `JREPL` and terminates when `JREPL` does.

If you want to come back to your script once the replacement is complete, use `call jrepl` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I've just found the same solution of the problem. Anyway, like to you for right realization!